# Fluffy creature

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

Can anyone help identify this little creature?  It was found in Gulf Shores, Al., USA. Approx. size 2-3 inches (5-7,5 cm)

[image]

Comment: What is its size?

Comment: Maybe 2-3 inches long, looked like it had guinea pig fur

Answer (score 4):

This is a caterpillar of a moth from the Genus [*Megalopyge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megalopyge_opercularis).

Here is another picture for comparison (the species here is *M. opercularis*, also known as "puss caterpillar"):

[image]

Another one:

[image]

And here is an imago (adult), also *M. opercularis*:

[image]

Comment: Good god, that is a very fluffy moth.

Comment: The moths are called "Flannel Moths" for a _very_ good reason ...